# how to use matplotlib multiple line chart without showing the y axis for one of the lines?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a `pandas df`:

I want to plot three of the columns on a single chart, the code I am using:

```
plt.plot( m1df['timestamp'],m1df['375'] ,marker='', color='skyblue', linewidth=2)
plt.plot( m1df['timestamp'],m1df['second_sum'], marker='', color='olive', linewidth=2)
plt.plot( m1df['timestamp'],m1df['close'], marker='', color='olive', linewidth=2, linestyle='dashed')
plt.legend()
```

The problem:

m1df['close'] values are very high: 20k - 30k range while `second_sum` and `375` are in range -100 to 200. I want the line of m1df['close'] to stay close to the range of -100 to 200. \

I think this would be doable by not showing the 'close' y-axis and setting a range on the y-axis?

I want to be able to read the value of the 'close' when I move pointer to it though.

Very new to `matplotlib` thanks for your help.

Comment: How about scaling your "close"-yaxis to a 200-300 scale (instead of 20k-30k)? This way you could show all data in 1 graph. Another option would be to multiplot in 2 rows with a shared xaxis.

Comment: @MigB looking up the code for shared axis now. Thanks!